# Unable to find reason behind JProfiler connection error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key

Tags: java, kubernetes, jprofiler

I am trying to connect locally running JProfiler(Evaluation version) to application running on google cloud Kubernetes cluster. Whenever I select application(pod) from the list. I get following error.

[image: Connection error]

Tried searching through various articles, but unable to find any specific resolution for this.

I am able to connect the same JProfiler to all other Java applications(Pods) on same Kubernetes cluster.

Is there something which needs to be changed at application level or I am missing anything?

Comment: Please check if the file $TMPDIR/jprofiler_error.log exists and add the exception there to the question, otherwise please contact support@ej-technologies.com and we'll figure out how to debug this.

Comment: I am not able to find the mentioned file. I've sent email to support@ej-technologies.com